# VIX Calculation - weighting of strikes

Tags: options, vix

The formula for calculating the VIX from SPX options is given on page 4 of this document:

https://www.cboe.com/micro/vix/vixwhite.pdf

My question is, why is the option price at each strike weighted by the inverse of the strike price squared?  This would seem to overweight OTM put options (with low strikes) and underweight OTM call options (with high strikes).

Comment: Overweight/underweight compared to what? That formula involving $1/K^2$ is called the "fair variance swap" [ link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_swap#Pricing_and_valuation ] formula and is how variance can be recovered from option prices.It is an important and non-obvious result.

Comment: This question has been asked before, see this link https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/why-is-the-vix-computed-that-way?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other comments already suggest this topic has been discussed many times and the references / links that are provided are far more detailed than my quick solution below.

In the construction / replication of a variance swap one tries to achieve a **CONSTANT** **dollar gamma**. This is done by buying a strip of calls and puts, weighted by 1/K^2 as you suggested. Now why did I all-cap the word CONSTANT? because the dollar gamma = $\gamma S^2$. As you can see the black scholes gamma is scaled by the squared level of the stock price. So to get a constant dollar gamma you need to have more of the lower strike options else they won't generate enough dollar gamma because the level of the stock is too low.

Comment: Thanks.  The paper about volatility swaps by Demeterfi et al at http://elis.sigmath.es.osaka-u.ac.jp/research/gs-volatility_swaps.pdf seems to go into this in depth.